# WinUI 3 - Updating UI Thead From Inside Async Method

Tags: c#, winui-3

## Background

I am developing an app using WinUI 3. At one spot, the user clicks a button to load data from an API, and the logic pulls the data in chunks. I want to show the status, with a bound TextBlock that shows the current number of records pulled in from the API as it's running, until it finishes and retrieves everything.

*Note: This is WinUI 3. It is not WPF, and it is not UWP. There are lots of answers for how to accomplish what I need to accomplish in WPF and UWP. But WinUI 3 seems to be just different enough to not work.*

## My Code

### First Attempt

```
LoadData = new RelayCommand<object>(
    async (parameter) =>
    {

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Initializing";

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this._jobService.LoadData(
                jobToRun: this.CurrentJob,
                onProgressCallback: ((countRecordsLoaded) => {
                    this.CurrentJob.Status = "Running";
                    this.CurrentJob.ExportCount = countRecordsLoaded;
                })
            );;
        });

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Complete";

    }

);
```

This fails with an error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

So I researched, and found the DispatcherQueue.

### Second Attempt

```
LoadData = new RelayCommand<object>(
    async (parameter) =>
    {

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Initializing";

        dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        {
            this._jobService.LoadData(
                jobToRun: this.CurrentJob,
                onProgressCallback: ((countRecordsLoaded) => {
                    this.CurrentJob.Status = "Running";
                    this.CurrentJob.ExportCount = countRecordsLoaded;
                })
            );;
        });

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Complete";

    }

);
```

This just runs synchronously, which won't work for me because it can sometimes take 30seconds or more.

### Third Attempt (Nesting Task.Run inside DispatcherQueue)

```
LoadData = new RelayCommand<object>(
    async (parameter) =>
    {

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Initializing";

        dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        {
            _ = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                this._jobService.LoadData(
                    jobToRun: this.CurrentJob,
                    onProgressCallback: ((countRecordsLoaded) => {
                        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Running";
                        this.CurrentJob.ExportCount = countRecordsLoaded;
                    })
                );;
            });
        });

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Complete";

    }

);
```

This goes back to the first error.

### More Attempts

I tried using both variations (`DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue` and `DispatcherQueue.EnqueueAsync`). They seem to function identically. I've tried awaiting and not awaiting both inside and outside. I've tried putting the dispatcherqueue part inside the task.run. I can get it to error out, and I can get it to run synchronously. But I can't get it to update the UI from within something running async.

## Question

How do update the UI thread from inside a truly async method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution for this (on all .NET UI platforms) is [progress reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#progress-reporting-optional). Ideally, `LoadData` would take an `IProgres<T>` instead of a callback method, but you can work with a lambda, too.

```
LoadData = new RelayCommand<object>(
    async (parameter) =>
    {
        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Initializing";
        IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(countRecordsLoaded =>
        {
            this.CurrentJob.Status = "Running";
            this.CurrentJob.ExportCount = countRecordsLoaded;
        });

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this._jobService.LoadData(
                jobToRun: this.CurrentJob,
                onProgressCallback: progress.Report
            );
        });

        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Complete";
    }
);
```

What's actually happening is that `Progress<T>` captures the current synchronization context (which is tied to the dispatcher queue on WinUI). Then, whenever a background thread calls `Report`, it queues up that update to the UI thread instead of running it directly.

Comment: That's works. I'd actually just figured it out with using a direct action as well, before I saw your message. The key is to wrap the `dispatcherQueue` directly around the logic that updates the UI, which means maybe passing it down as a variable. But using iProgress, I don't have to futz with it, which is great. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post another answer here, because I ran into some problems with just using Progress, and ended up having to use DispatcherQueue anyway. Because of that, I was able to use nested actions and clean up the code quite a bit. Here is another working version:

```
LoadData = new RelayCommand<object>(
    async (parameter) =>
    {

        var dispatcherQueue = Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
            {
                this.CurrentJob.Status = "Initializing";
            });

            this._jobService.LoadData(
                jobToRun: this.CurrentJob,
                onProgressCallback: ((countRecordsLoaded) => {
                    dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                    {
                        this.CurrentJob.Status = "Running";
                        this.CurrentJob.ExportCount = countRecordsLoaded;
                    });
                })
            );

            dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
            {
                this.CurrentJob.Status = "Complete";
            });

        });

    }

);
```

The big benefit of this is that you have isolated your code inside the task, and you can then run a synchronous loop, for example. In this example case, I want to run 10 jobs in a row. If I have the loop outside the `Task.Run()`, then they'll all try to run at the same time, but I want them to run in order, so my loop has to be inside the `Task.Run()`.

Example with sync loop inside the async task:

```
LoadData = new RelayCommand<object>(
    async (parameter) =>
    {

        var dispatcherQueue = Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            foreach (Job runningJob in this.QueuedJobs)
            {

                dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                {
                    runningJob.Status = "Initializing";
                });

                this._jobService.LoadData(
                    jobToRun: runningJob,
                    onProgressCallback: ((countRecordsLoaded) => {
                        dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                        {
                            runningJob.Status = "Running";
                            runningJob.ExportCount = countRecordsLoaded;
                        });
                    })
                );

                dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                {
                    runningJob.Status = "Complete";
                });

            }

        });

    }

);
```